# Align inline an Html element with flex property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a dynamic application. I have a div tag with flex-direction: column property. Is it possible to add a span tag inside that div with text align in parallel?

```css
.parent {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    Item 1
    <span style="border: 1px solid;">item 2</span>
</div>
```

But the text displaying with a line break. One important thing is I don't have edit the class '.parent'.

Comment: Can I see the blueprint that you want?

Comment: A flex container with `column` direction will stack child elements (including anonymous elements, like unwrapped text) vertically. If you cannot edit the container styles, then your only flex option for horizontal alignment would be to wrap the child elements in a nested flex container with `row` direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
body{
  display: flex;
}
.parent {
   flex: 1 1;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    Item 1
    <span style="border: 1px solid;">item 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The question states that the `.parent` class cannot be altered.